# Keep appending to list until a character amount is reached

Tags: python, string

I wish to take a list and append the values to another list until a character limit of 59 is reached.

If the new list is at a character amount of say 54 and the next value won't fit within the limit, stop appending to the new list.

I've tried the beneath with my limited py knowledge

```
shortest_titles = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet']
title_limited = []
counter = 0
while counter < 70:
    for i in shortest_titles:
        title_limited.append(i)

    counter += len(i)

print(title_limited)
```

Comment: You are counting array elements, not characters inside them, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: After checking the length of the result you add *all values at once*. Instead, you need to add them *one at a time* and check the result length *after each one*. You have two nested loops, but you need only one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your approach as shown below (to perform a proper *rotation*):

while loop is retained for cases when the overall input list length (in chars) is less than 59.

```
shortest_titles = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'amet']
title_limited = []
counter = 0
while counter < 59:
    for i in shortest_titles:
        counter += len(i)
        if counter > 59: break
        title_limited.append(i)

print(title_limited)   # ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet']
print(len(''.join(title_limited)))  # 56
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, works a dream. I'm guessing you were down-voted by another submitter, have an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
shortest_titles = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet']
title_limited = []
c = 0
for i in shortest_titles:
    c += len(i)
    if c >= 59:
        break
    title_limited.append(i)
print(title_limited)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import numpy as np

shortest_titles_cumlen = np.cumsum([len(el) for el in shortest_titles])
n=70 # character limit
res=[shortest_titles[i] for i in range(0, len(shortest_titles)) if shortest_titles_cumlen[i]<n]
```

Comment: Your list comprehension is unnecessarily complex. For the first one, just do `[len(t) for t in shortest_titles]` or `[*map(len,shortest_titles)]`. The former is easier to understand while the latter has slightly better performance.

Comment: Cheers, that was my first thinking, but then I got involved in the second line, and somehow it slipped my attention, that I don't need to use "range" in the first...

Comment: The second one can also be simplified: `[t for t, l in zip(shortest_titles, shortest_titles_cumlen) if l<=n]`. Another alternative is `shortest_titles[:np.searchsorted(shortest_titles_cumlen, n, "right")]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `itertools`. First create a new list that contains length of each sublist using `map(len, shortest_titles)`, find the total length of chars upto that list using `accumulate`, then `zip` this with the original list to iterate in pairs, and finally use `takewhile` to extract sublist till the total accumulated lenght is less than 59

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile,accumulate
>>> [l for l,_ in takewhile(lambda t: t[1]<59, zip(shortest_titles, accumulate(map(len, shortest_titles))))]
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet']
```